# Best way to remove partially stripped and rusted fuel filter nut?

Tags: rust, fuel-filter, stuck-bolt

I missed the memo about replacing my fuel filter every 30k, so it's been more like 100k since it's been replaced. Anyway, the car is a 2001 Buick Regal, and the fuel filter nut (not the quick connect, but the side closest to the front of the car) is stripped and rusted, and looks *very* similar to this

[image]

I've tried spraying White Lithium Grease on it to loosen it up, I'm going to have to get a 16mm wrench since it's stripped (It ***was*** a 17mm nut), but I'd really like to avoid towing it to the shop (won't run, fuel system issue) if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing you need to get some type of penetrating oil. You need something like LiquidWrench,PB Blaster or SeaFoam. My personal favorite is PB Blaster. The second thing you need is patience. If you can, give the penetrant several days to work. I have had goodluck wrapping the fitting in a strip of rag and soaking it with the oil.  If you can get the quick disconnect side off hold the fuel line fitting and try to spin the filter. This will hopefully prevent the fuel line fitting from twisting the steel line. In the worst case look for a clean or lightly rusted section close to the filter that can be cut and reflared. Harbor freight has a flaring kit for about $25. Then install a short piece of new steel line.

Comment: Also, use a [flare nut wrench](http://garagejournal.com/forum/showthread.php?t=157673) rather than the open end of a combination wrench (or worse yet an adjustable!)

Comment: I didn't get a chance to actually get it off yet, the fuel pump was the no-start culprit, but I marked it as the answer nonetheless. I've been spraying the PB Blaster on it to loosen it up though.